# Get value of dynamically added input

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have a form with possibility to add additional input fields. I get those values with $_POST['input_name'] and can insert to db / send mail. The problem is that I want those fields and values be displayed when page is refreshed if there was errors left, but I can't get values of dynamically added inputs in Jquery code - just the first one which is added statically. Is it possible to get those values in jQuery code?

My HTML

```
<div class="field_wrapper">
<div>
 <input type="text" name="input_name[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter name" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['input_name'])) echo $_POST['input_name'][0];?>"/>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add field"></a>
</div>

 </div>
```

My jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    console.log(jQuery('#contactForm').serialize()); <- getting first value

    var vals = jQuery("input[name='input_name[]']").map(function(){ return this.value}).get();
    console.log(vals); <- getting first value
    var maxField = 10; //Input fields increment limitation
    var addButton = jQuery('.add_button'); //Add button selector
    var wrapper = jQuery('.field_wrapper'); //Input field wrapper

    var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1
    
    //Once add button is clicked
    jQuery(addButton).click(function(){
        //Check maximum number of input fields
        if(x < maxField){ 
            var fieldHTML = '<div><input type="text" name="input_name[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter name"/> \
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button"></a></div>'; 
            x++; //Increment field counter
            jQuery(fieldHTML).appendTo(wrapper); //Add field html
        }
    });
    
    //Once remove button is clicked
    jQuery(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery(this).parent('div').remove(); //Remove field html
        x--; //Decrement field counter
    });
});
```

Comment: Save them in `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` and then retrieve them when the page is reloaded.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I tried to serialize values after submiting before refreshing the page and values are displayed. I think I will be able to retrieve them